# Error in Views override template "Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in include()"

Tags: 7, views, theming

So I am theming a View with a template in my theme folder.

I am getting this error message:

"Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in include()"

This is the code:

```
<?php print ($fields["title"]->content); ?>
```

I've tried adding an IF statement like below (is my syntax correct???) and clearing the cache but the issue persists:

```
<?php if ($fields["title"]->content) { print ($fields["title"]->content); } ?>
```

P.S. the field is printing, it's just that there is an error message displayed in addition.

Also, by the way, I am using views-view-fields.tpl.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `isset()` to avoid such notices:

```
<?php if (isset($fields["title"])) { print ($fields["title"]->content); } ?>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. I have applied this line but the error persists. I actually already tried this but just didn't mention in my post. Anything else I can try?

Comment: Oops. Made a small edit because the notice would still occur when there is no key 'title' in the `$fields` array.

Comment: Hmm... i still get the error? I'm using: <?php if (isset($fields["title"])) { print ($fields["title"]->content); } ?>

Comment: When checking /admin/reports/dblog, Am getting  Undefined offset: 1include()
 in node template file. this is the mentioned line in node tpl file.

    $selected_l2 =  strip_tags($all_breadcrumb['breadcrumb']['1']);